# Prevent adding duplicate items from Clipboard to ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, uri, clipboard

How can I prevent adding duplicate links from Clipboard to ListBox?

Here's my codes.

I used Regex so that I can easily add if the Clipboard contains only URLs

```cs
private void AddLinks()
{
    string[] linkItems = Clipboard.GetText().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Regex regURL = new Regex("https:(.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    foreach (string link in linkItems)
    {
        MatchCollection url = regURL.Matches(link);
        LIST_URL.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (Match m in url)
        {
            LIST_URL.Items.Add(m);
        }
        LIST_URL.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: My question there is how I can avoid duplicate items in Listbox?
Everytime I add new link item. it must check if the link is already exist in listbox

Comment: Well, you have answered yourself: check if it is already in the list and add it only if it is not.

Comment: The Regex pattern will get the valid Urls of `https` scheme only. Addresses like `www.x.net`, `google.com`, `ftp://...`, ..etc. will be ignored. Is that what you want? Otherwise, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/10216583) post for more Regex patterns.

Comment: No it's not about regex. It's about avoiding duplicate items.
I just put the regex just in case someone will ask.
I'm fine with that regex. because I have only specific link to load not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex and the given pattern, to get Urls from the Clipboard if any, and insert the distinct Urls into a ListBox:

```cs
private void AddLinks() =>
    LIST_URL.Items.AddRange(
        Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(), @"https:(.*)*", 
            RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => !LIST_URL.Items.Cast<string>()
        .Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToArray()
        );
```

Also, you might want to try [Uri.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=netcore-3.1) method:

```cs
private void AddLinks() =>
    LIST_URL.Items.AddRange(Clipboard.GetText()
            .Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(line => Uri.TryCreate(line, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri)
            && uri != null && uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps
            && !LIST_URL.Items.Cast<string>()
            .Any(item => line.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .ToArray());
```

In both code snippets, the [Enumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) method in the `.where` scope excludes the duplicate Urls from the Clipboard and they - if any - won't be added to the list.

Comment: Wow this is what I'm looking for. 
I'm gonna try it now
Thank you so much

Comment: May I ask one more time? how I can use it for adding multiple files?
I'm using it now for other codes. but can't figure out for adding files from local

Comment: Sure. Something like: `listBox1.Items.AddRange(localFilesArray.Where(f => !listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(f, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ToArray());`

Comment: It worked again :) thank you very much. I don't need to use my old class to remove duplicates. this is much easier

Comment: Hello again @JQSOFT
I wanna ask how to use it for adding listview subitems? 
I'm currently using your code on my listbox and now my problem is for listview item. I want to prevent adding multiple item

Comment: @zackmark15 Hello there!. For `ListView` do  something like: `lvw.Items.AddRange(itemsToAddStringArray.Where(x => lvw.FindItemWithText(x, true, 0) == null).Select(x => new ListViewItem(new string[] { x, "sub1", "sub2", "sub..." })).ToArray());`

Comment: @zackmark15 I pasted in your new question. You don't wait Mr. Zack.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @jQSOFT
here's the final fixed codes. it worked 100%.

```
    private void AddLinks()
    {
        lbURL.Items.AddRange(Regex.Matches(Clipboard.GetText(), @"https?://www.viu.com/(.*)*",
            RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => !lbURL.Items.Cast<string>()
            .Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray());
    }
```

Another fixed by @jQSOFT  maybe might help others too.
Preventing duplicate when adding new items into listbox

```
 using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                ofd.Filter = "m3u8 File(*.m3u8)|*.m3u8";
                ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
                ofd.Multiselect = true;

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] files = ofd.FileNames;

                    List_URL.BeginUpdate();
                    List_URL.Items.AddRange
                                (files.Where(f => 
                                !List_URL.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => 
                                item.Equals(f, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ToArray());
                    List_URL.EndUpdate();
                }
            }
```